# Is there a way to read a file with inconsistent data using MFL in OSB11g

Tags: osb

Recently I got a requirement to read a file and insert those records into a DB. But, when I looked at the file it is not consistent, and the source team is not in a position to alter it in any way. So, is there a way to read it?

Example of a File:

```
Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4
Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4
Record1,Record2
Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4
Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4
Record1,Record2
Record1,Record2,Record3,Record4
```

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Regards,
Vishnu.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a comma-separated list of values and each new line forms a dataset.

You can use MFL Format Builder with delimiter as a comma and generate a standardized XML document out of your data.

This [link](https://www.soawork.com/2013/11/binary-to-xml-in-osb.html) has a good tutorial to get you started.